# How to compare 2 repositories (diffs)

Tags: git, github

I have uploaded to git using 2 repositories my code, one is May Release, second is June release.
In June release, I need to check what was changed according to May release.
May release is stable version

I have configured github + android, I have created 2 repos in github
2 projects are deployed to this repos.

Expected result is to see diffs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have **a single local repo** see both repos you are talking about as its remotes, fetch from both and then compare whatever branches you want with git diff

```
git fetch --all
git diff repo1/branch-A repo2/branch-B
```

That should do

Comment: where should I do fetch --all?

Comment: On the terminal. I guess that the same operation is available on an IDE once you have set up both remotes for your repo.

Comment: I mean, I have 2 android studios opened, with different projects, and I have 2 remotes

Comment: let me do a little adjustment on the response.  Done. A single repo can see more than one remote. Have _one repo_ to have both remote repos as its remotes, then you will be able to compare branches from them.